# How to get byobu to start at startup with a command executed, as root?

Tags: debian, command-line, gnu-screen, tmux, byobu

I want when the computer start, a byobu session is started and a command executed in the first window (windows 0), without requiring any user intervention.

It is very important that this doesn't require an actual user to login.

How to do that?

I suppose this byobu will be accessible later to user root (or if possible another user ?)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a command to be executed at boot time, you can put it in your [crontab](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5) with `@reboot` instead of a time. So run `crontab` and add a line like

```
@reboot byobu -S boot-time mycommand
```

Instead of putting the command on the command line of `byobu`, you can put it in a Byobu session file.

If you want the session to be executed as root, you can start it from `/etc/rc.local` instead of root's crontab. Be sure to start it in the background, since the boot isn't complete until `/etc/rc.local` has finished running.

```
byobu -S boot-time mycommand &
```

Answer (score 0):

Now **byobu** is based on tmux, the easiest way is to directly use **tmux**.

in my case I use the following syntax:

```
tmux new -d -s session-name /path/to/my/Script.sh
```

and connect to it I use:

```
tmux session has -t-name
```

in your crontab you will have to enter:

```
@reboot tmux new -d -s session-name /path/to/my/Script.sh
```